# Tensorflow Lite: boolean scalar as input tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

How to set a boolean scalar as input when converting `Tensorflow` model to `TFLITE` model?

I am trying to convert the [Facenet Tensor-flow](https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet) model into `TFLITE` format which I could use for an Android app. This Facenet model takes a tensor containing image data and a boolean scalar as input:

```
feed_dict = { images_placeholder: images, phase_train_placeholder:False }
```

I follow the [Tensorflow lite guide](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/docs_src/mobile/tflite/devguide.md) to convert models into TFLITE format. Here is an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

img = tf.placeholder(name="img", dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1, 64, 64, 3))
val = img + tf.constant([1., 2., 3.]) + tf.constant([1., 4., 4.])
out = tf.identity(val, name="out")

with tf.Session() as sess:
  tflite_model = tf.contrib.lite.toco_convert(sess.graph_def, [img], [out])
  open("converteds_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Here is my code:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():

        with tf.Session() as sess:

            # Load the model
            facenet.load_model(args.model)

            # Get input and output tensors
            images_placeholder = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("input:0")
            embeddings = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("embeddings:0")
            phase_train_placeholder = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("phase_train:0")
            #reshape as tflite does not accepts None dimension
            images_placeholder = tf.reshape(images_placeholder, [1,160,160,3])
            tflite_model = tf.contrib.lite.toco_convert(sess.graph_def, [images_placeholder, phase_train_placeholder], [embeddings])
            open("converteds_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

The program gives an error saying (I guess this happens as `tflite` does not support `tf.bool` just yet):

```
File "/.../facenet/tensorflow1.8/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/convert.py", line 206, in toco_convert
    input_tensor.dtype))
ValueError: Tensors phase_train:0 not known type tf.bool
```

If I cast the `phase_train_placeholder` to the supported type `tf.int32`, just to see how it goes. Then it gives another error (I guess this happens as the convert function does not accept scalar):

```
File "/.../facenet/tensorflow1.8/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/convert.py", line 217, in toco_convert
    input_array.shape.dims.extend(map(int, input_tensor.get_shape()))
  File "/.../facenet/tensorflow1.8/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 591, in __iter__
    raise ValueError("Cannot iterate over a shape with unknown rank.")
ValueError: Cannot iterate over a shape with unknown rank.
```

Could you please suggest an workaround for this? I understand that TFLite is still in development but I could try to contribute this part if it is possible. Many thanks.